# Compare 2 spark dataframes in Java using new column to print the result

Tags: json, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Apache Spark and I am trying to compare two json files using **JAVA**. I have two dataframes 1) expected data and 2) actual data.

**Expected data - table_1**[image]

**Actual data - table_2**[image]

**Differences**[image]

I need it to compare each column to be **exact** and to take the **expected dataframe** and to include another column called **'result' where it gives pass or fail.** For example the differences is *emp_id 4*. Therefore the column will look as follows; pass, pass, pass, fail.

Can anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the two data frames have exactly the same columns names, you can compare them by joined that two dataframe by all of the columns.

```
val allColumns = dataframe1.columns.toSeq

val diffDf = dataframe1.join(dataframe2, allColumns)
```

The default join type is an inner join, therefore you receive in the diffDf all the common rows between those two data frames.

If you want to receive in the diffDf all the different rows between the two dataframe just use the full outer type like this:

```
val diffDf = dataframe1.join(dataframe2, allColumns, "fullouter")
```

You can play with the join types to receive your required diffDf.

Comment: Using Java. I believe the above is Scala